# Jenkins couldn't run exe installer

Tags: powershell, jenkins, installation, admin, privileges

Created Jenkins job to run silent installation of my application, the application installer is exe file.

1. tried with Windows Exe Runner - setup.exe /s
2. tried with PowerShell job -  - setup.exe /s

In both cases I get the same issue:

System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

If I run the command manually on the machine from PS run as administrator it will silently install my application in the background without errors.

Suppose it is problem with Jenkins privileges on the server machine, Jenkins is run as a service using Admin credentials.

Comment: This is most likely due to [session 0 isolation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361). Even if you run a setup.exe "silently" it is still a GUI application and doesn't expect the restrictions applied to session 0. What is the scenario where you have to run a setup.exe from Jenkins? I'm trying to get the bigger picture here.

Comment: Here is the output from App installation log "App setup is not running as administrator. It will restart running as administrator".

Comment: I created Task Scheduler job to run the same job and I have the same error when set it to "Run whenever user is logged on or not" if it is set to "Run only when user is looged on" it works properly, install application in silent mode without any UI appears.